# Optimize Cross Join Performance LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, entity-framework-4

Cross join in LINQ is taking very long time.
Using Profiler i had found which query is taking long time

Below is the source Code

MODEL CODE

```
 1. List<TO_ShiftSchedule> tempShiftSch= new List<TO_ShiftSchedule>();
 public class TO_ShiftSchedule
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string ShiftId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ShiftDate { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime? Doj { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public EmployeeStatus EmpStatus { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public bool FlagProcess { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public bool FlagOT { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string FlagWeekoff { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public bool CheckedIds { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<TO_ShiftSchedule> List { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public double StartTime { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public double EndTime { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

2. List<TO_TempInOut> listTempInOut = new List<TO_TempInOut>();\


    public class TO_TempInOut
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int CompanyId { get; set; }
            public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
            public int InOutTime { get; set; }
            public DateTime InDate { get; set; }
            public string InOutFlag { get; set; }
            public string Time_Field1 { get; set; }
            public string Time_Field2 { get; set; }
            public string Time_Field3 { get; set; }
            public string Time_Field4 { get; set; }
            public string Time_Field5 { get; set; }
            public DateTime Time_Date1 { get; set; }
            public string Time_Field6 { get; set; }

        }
```

---

```
Datetime InputDate ="01/11/2016"
Datetime DtTodate="30/11/2016"
while (InputDate <= DtTodate) => 30 Records
     {
       foreach (var item in ShiftDetails) => 9 Records
         {

           var data = (from B in tempShiftSch  **=>178 Records**
                       from C in listTempInOut **=>113851 Records**
                       where
                       B.CompanyId == companyId &&
                       C.CompanyId == companyId &&
                       B.EmployeeId == C.EmployeeId &&
                       C.InDate >= StrOutStart &&
                       C.InDate <= StrOutEnd &&
                       B.ShiftId == item.ShiftCode &&
                       B.ShiftDate == tempInputDate
                       select new
                                {
                                    C.EmployeeId,
                                    C.InDate,
                                    C.Time_Date1
                                }).ToList();


                        }
                     }
```

Using Profier i have found above query is taking 95% of execution time
[image]

I want to optimize above code so that process become faster and yield result quickly

Comment: I think it's because you use it in a `while` and `for` loop. LINQ loops through all records in your lists each time.

Comment: So is everything indexed appropriately? I'd strongly advise against using string for dates, by the way... and this is currently pseudocode, which makes it harder to help you. It does sound like you should just have *one* query rather than having two outer loops though...

Comment: @JonSkeet i had just added query which is taking long time, other logic is also present in For Each Loop which modifies the `tempShiftSch ` list, so it is not possible to merge the outer loop and query

Comment: But if you group by date, you can still handle the results that way.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry but im not getting properly how to group by using dates

Comment: As is, you are executing almost the same query 270 times. Perhaps, you could execute your query only once without Shiftcode and shiftdate params, keep the result in a variable and use a simple select with this two parameters in each loop.
Anyway, if you tell us what do you want to do exactly with your query, we could help you better...

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you provide some sample code.!

Comment: @Anup: Not when we've only got pseudo-code and don't know half the types involved, no.

Comment: Jon is right. The question is tagged `entity-framework`, but it's unclear what's the context of the problematic query. e.g. what is the type of `tempShiftSch` - `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`? Same for `listTempInOut`.

Comment: Have you tried to use join with proper condition?

Comment: @JonSkeet I had added my models in question to know the data types.  i had follow the Tistkle suggestion and found performance increased by 50-60%  but still if there is any other way to optimize more it would be great

Comment: Ok, so `listTempInOut` is a list. But what is `tempShiftSch`?

Comment: It's still pseudo-code (and badly formatted at that) making it harder to help you, and there's a lot that seems unnecessary. Code samples should be as complete as possible, but also minimal. Please bear in mind that the aim of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers.